# Texto temporário em JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Gostaria de trocar o texto de um `JLabel` e deixa-lo por apenas alguns segundos, depois voltar o texto anterior. Tenho que executar um método que leva alguns segundos para ficar pronto e gostaria de notificar o usuário de que está sendo executado e deste modo pareceu-me mais simples.

Da forma abaixo não funciona como esperado:

```
jLabel1.setText("texto);
```

Comment: Como assim? Você quer alterar o texto de um jlabel por algum tempo e depois voltar ao texto anterior?

Comment: Exatamente isto !

Comment: No caso tenho que executar um método que leva alguns segundos para ficar pronto e gostaria de notificar o usuário de que está sendo executado e deste modo pareceu-me mais simples. Se você souber alguma outra forma mais simples ou eficiente de fazer isto acontecer eu também ficaria grato em saber.

Comment: Tá usando swing? Se sim, provavelmente vai precisar usar [SwingWorker](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Comment: Vou pesquisar a respeito, obrigado por ajudar :D

Comment: Foi uma sugestão, mas logo logo alguém responde com um exemplo pratico.

Comment: Por que não troca o texto normalmente (do jeito que você está fazendo) e - quando esse método demorado terminar - você troca de novo exatamente do mesmo jeito? (claro que levando em conta o *thread* certo, seja via `SwingWorker` ou de qualquer outro meio)

Comment: Então, sou novato e não sei como posso fazer isto. Vou procurar algum material sobre Thread pra ver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>A pergunta é antiga, mas já que ninguém respondeu, resolvi deixar uma solução que desenvolvi por acaso.</sub>

---

É possível fazer esta restauração de texto usando [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Lembrando que, caso esse tempo de espera seja para executar algo mais demorado, você pode delegar ao `SwingWorker` essa atividade também, dentro do método `doInBackground()`. Veja um exemplo abaixo, onde eu personalizei uma classe que estende `JLabel`, configurando um método exclusivo para essa finalidade:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JLabelWithTimerTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CustomLabel label;
    private JButton btn;
    private JPanel pane;

    public JLabelWithTimerTest() {
        setTitle("JLabel with Timer");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        setContentPane(pane);

        label = new CustomLabel("Texto inicial...");
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.gridx = 1;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        gbc1.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc1.weighty = 1.0;
        pane.add(label, gbc1);

        btn = new JButton("disparar");
        btn.addActionListener(e -> label.setTransientText("texto temporario", 2000));

        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = (GridBagConstraints) gbc1.clone();
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridy = 3;
        pane.add(btn, gbc2);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class CustomLabel extends JLabel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker;

        public CustomLabel() {
            super();
        }

        public CustomLabel(String text) {
            super.setText(text);
        }

        public void setTransientText(String text, long duration) {

            if (worker != null && !worker.isDone()) return;

            final String originalText = getText();
            worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    setText(text);
                    Thread.sleep(duration);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    setText(originalText);
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(JLabelWithTimerTest::new);
    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método `SetTransientText()` recebe o texto temporário e a duração, em milissegundos. No exemplo, o texto dura 2 segundos.

Lembrando que, pelo fato do `SwinWorker` rodar numa Thread a parte, o `Thread.sleep` não trava a interface gráfica.